# What causes this weird app life-cycle?

Tags: android

My Android app checks if a specific service is not running, in my Activity's onResume method. If it hasn't been started, then it goes into the background (via startService) and stays there for an action. Clicking on a button causes the service to go into the foreground and it works great. Now the problem:

Scenario #1 :

The foreground service has a button, which sends it back to the background and stops it. I click on it and after that I close my app (the activities from the recents view). Even the Android monitor shows me that it's not running and works as it should.

Scenario #2: (The not expected behavior)

First I close the app (the activities) and then I click on the service's close button. In this case, I can clearly see that my app still uses the same amount of memory it used while the activities were opened. When I reopen my app, I can see that it continues working where I left it (at least the internal app variables don't get garbage collected) Sometimes the CPU usage monitor shows that methods get called, but not from my app. Only Android SDK functions. I couldn't see objects kept in the memory, but a lot of chat[], String, FinalizerReferences etc...

What could cause this? Ruined context lifecycle? Memory leak?

Comment: "The foreground service has a button . . ." - A `Service` does not have a UI.  Please explain what you mean by a service.

Comment: But a foreground service has a notification. My notification has a button (an action).